# SQL not properly recognizing and honoring the WHERE statement

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables.

```
DECLARE @definitions TABLE
( fDefId varchar(8)   ,
  dType  varchar(MAX) ,
  fName  varchar(MAX)
)

INSERT @definitions values('8c7eab0e','string','custpartno')
INSERT @definitions values('8c7eab02','int'   ,'itemno'    )

DECLARE @fields TABLE
( rowId varchar(8)   ,
  fkFId varchar(8)   ,
  adj   varchar(MAX)
)

INSERT @fields values('83EDE211','8c7eab0e','89319971151801')
INSERT @fields values('83EDE211','8c7eab02','1'             )
```

I am trying to find the records in `@fields` where the value is not an `int` and the related record in the `@definitions` table has a `dType` value of `'int'`.

When I try to get this list of results (if any), I tried these statements:

```
SELECT f.rowId ,
       f.fkFId ,
       f.adj   ,
       d.fName
  FROM @fields      f
  JOIN @definitions d ON  f.fkFId = d.fDefId
                      AND d.dType = 'int'
  WHERE ISNUMERIC( adj        ) <> 1
     OR CAST(      adj AS INT ) <> adj

SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT f.rowId ,
              f.fkFId ,
              f.adj   ,
              d.fName
       FROM @fields      f
       JOIN @definitions d ON  f.fkFId = d.fDefId
                           AND d.dType='int'
     ) a
WHERE ISNUMERIC( adj        ) <> 1
   OR CAST(      adj AS INT ) <> adj
```

and got this error with both:

```
The conversion of the varchar value '89319971151801' overflowed an int column.
```

However, when I first store the values in a table variable like this:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
( rowId    varchar(8),
  fDefId   varchar(8),
  adjusted varchar(MAX)
)

INSERT @temp
SELECT f.rowId ,
       f.fkFId ,
       f.adj
FROM @fields      f
JOIN @definitions d ON  f.fkFId = d.fDefId
                    AND d.dType = 'int'

SELECT * FROM @temp
WHERE ISNUMERIC( adjusted        ) <> 1
   OR CAST(      adjusted AS INT ) <> adjusted
```

I get the expected results (no records in this example).

If I remove the `WHERE` clause I get these results:

[image]

The row with the large field isn't there, so why would it cause an error after adding the `WHERE`?

I can also avoid the issue by casting as `BIGINT` instead of `INT`, but why would that matter since the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses remove the value that is not an `INT` from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do know that the SQL Standard has no requirements mandating a specific order of expression evaluation or short-circuiting of expression evaluation? The query optimizer is free to rearrange pretty much the entire query so long as the semantic meaning (not intent) is maintained.

Your second stab at things, pre-filtering on `datetype = 'int'` and loading the filtered results works because that forces an order of operation on the query processor.

Your single-query tries fail because the expression

```
CAST( adj AS INT ) <> adj
```

Which

- takes a `varchar`
- converts it to an `int`
- converts that `int` back into a `varchar`, and finally...
- compars that `varchar` (containing a normalized/canonical string representation of the `int`) back to the original `varchar` value.

Fails. It fails because the query processor must evaluate that expression for *every candidate row*, regardless of whether or not the column `datatype` contains `int` or not.

The second single-query attempt, with the derived table in the `from` clause fails because the optimizer is smart enough to see that the query can be refactored so as to not use a derived table.

The real problem, of course, is that you have a denormalized database design and you're overloading the meaning (and data type) of the column `adj`, trying to make a single table be multiple things.

Comment: I always thought the WHERE clause was evaluated as a whole.  I didn't know it would/could do it one part at a time.

Comment: We had to use this design to acheive our desired results for this part of our application. It is for importing records from a text file and we need to track and display meta info for each field and value and allow pivoting back and forth.  We also have made it easy to add additional fields to the import process.

Comment: I am guessing then that last approach is in fact the best for me as it will reduce the number of records in the evaluation of whether or not it is an `int`.  Is that true, or is there a better way given the design constraints?

Comment: That's what I would think. You might want to consider using a proper temp table (`create table #foo ...`) rather than a table variable. Table variables tend to have performance problems if the size of the table variable gets much beyond "a few rows" (for some definition of "a few"). You might try also putting a clustered primary key on your temp table to improve the join. The query processor doesn't use indices on temp table, but a clustered index make the index's B-tree the head containing the table's data pages. It allows the query optimizer to to an index seek when it would otherwise scan.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.  Because it is short lived, and applies to only a single column in the pivoted table, I wouldn't expect the table variable to have more than a thousand rows (on the high side).  The average will probably have 100-300 rows.  I am not expecting that to make much difference, but can't hurt to check.